# convert array_chunk from php to java

Tags: java, php

my php code is:

```
$splitArray = array_chunk($theArray,ceil(count($theArray) / 2),true);
```

Comment: Splendid. What's your Java code?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i havent got any idea for this:) i am not a java programmer.

Comment: what do you want to do with array chunk?

Comment: i want to do this: $splitArray = array_chunk($theArray,ceil(count($theArray) / 2),true);

Comment: what does this do exactly?  We don't know PHP, so your reply might help

Comment: I suspect you don't need to create the two arrays in the first place. If you let us know what you do with these arrays, they might be avoided completely.

Answer (score 3):

php's `array_chunk` function splits an array into chunks of the size you specify. You can do this in Java, by using `Arrays.copyOfRange` and passing in the start and end points. Here is some sample code:

```
/**
 * Chunks an array into size large chunks. 
 * The last chunk may contain less than size elements. 
 * @param <T>
 * @param arr The array to work on 
 * @param size The size of each chunk 
 * @return a list of arrays
 */
public static <T> List<T[]> chunk(T[] arr, int size) {

    if (size <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size must be > 0 : " + size);

    List<T[]> result = new ArrayList<T[]>();

    int from = 0;
    int to = size >= arr.length ? arr.length : size;

    while (from < arr.length) {
        T[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, from, to);
        from = to;
        to += size;
        if (to > arr.length) {
            to = arr.length;
        }
        result.add(subArray);
    }
    return result;
}
```

For example, to create chunks of size two:

```
String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"} ;
List<String[]> chunks = chunk(arr,2);
```

Which will return three arrays:

```
{a,b}
{c,d}
{e}
```

Comment: The method copyOfRange(T[], int, int) is undefined for the type Arrays

Comment: Which version of java are you using? It is defined. See the docs here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T[],%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

Java only supports numeric arrays, so you this will only work for a numeric array which  has no gaps. If u need a solution to deal with non-numeric values (i.e. Maps) post back, and I'll look into it.

```
public void testMethod() {
    Object[] array={"one","two","three","four","five"};

    Object[][] chunkedArray = array_chunk(array,2);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(chunkedArray));


}

public Object[][] array_chunk(Object[] array,int size/*,FALSE Arrays are always numeric in java*/){
    Object[][] target= new Object[(array.length + size -1) / size][];

    for (int i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        int innerArraySize=array.length-i*size>=size?size:array.length-i*size;
        Object[] inner=new Object[innerArraySize];
        System.arraycopy(array, i*size, inner, 0, innerArraySize);
        target[i]=inner;
    }

    return target;
}
```